# Problem by creating nodes in loop

Tags: nodes, bootstrapping

i am new to drupal and trying to migrate same pages to drupal. I am able to create one node via druapals API, but when trying to create more nodes in a loop it doesn't work...

This is the working code:

```
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT','/var/www');
    require '/var/www/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);        


    #construct the new node object
    $node = new stdClass();

    #specify node properties
    $node->uid = 1;
    $node->title = "new node";
    $node->log ="";
    $node->status = 1;
    $node->comment = 1;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->sticky = 0;
    $node->type = 'veranstaltung';
    $node->language = 'und';
    $node->created = time();
    $node->changed = $node->created;
    $node->tnid=0;
    $node->translate=0;
    $node->body['und'][0]['value']="<h1>content</h1>";
    $node->body['und'][0]['format']="filtered_html";
    $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value']="<h1>content</h1>";

    #save node
    node_save($node)
```

If i put this in a for-loop and change the body and title each iteration it doesn't work.. The code is inside an external php script. Even copy the code and paste behind it again with other body and title does not work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Better run this script using Drush. It's very easy to use it for running scripts. It'll automaticaaly bootstrap Drupal.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference in PHP; therefore `$node->nid` is being set after your first go around the for loop.  If `$node->nid` is set, no new node is created, so, I'd `unset($node->nid)` after each `node_save()` and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in PHP; therefore `$node->nid` is being set after your first go around the for loop. If `$node->nid` is set, no new node is created, so, I'd `unset($node->nid)` after each `node_save()` and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Try function [node_object_prepare()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7)

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'thing';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->title = 'Test thing';
// ...more node properties...
node_save($node);
$nid = $node->nid;
print 'nid of the node I just created: ' . $nid;
```

You can also include your code in a custom module in a hook_init() or a hook_cron(), you'll not need to boostrap drupal